# Push notifications HTML5

Tags: html, cordova

I'm building a web app in HTML5/Phonegap targeting Android and iOS platforms. I'm using a tool that takes my HTML5 code and transforms my web app in a native application for Android or iOS. Now I would like to include in my web app push notifications so when something happens on the server, the app will trigger a native notification. What are the free solutions I might use to do this? I read about Pushwoosh and UrbanAirship but it seems both aren't free.

Thanks!

Comment: Holly Schinsky recently posted about plugins that use APNS and GCM for iOS and Android respectively. http://devgirl.org/2013/01/24/push-notifications-plugin-support-added-to-phonegap-build/

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it in more detail, seems it's exactly what I am looking for. @SimonMacDonald

Comment: Unlike UA, Pushwoosh is completely free for sending out unlimited notifications to up to 1M subscribers. It covers 95% of the apps on the market.